# Is it true to say that "Everything is a component in React"?

Tags: reactjs

Is it true to say that:

> Everything is a component in React

Comment: Essentially yes. Everything that ReactDOM (Reacts synthetic DOM) renders is a stateless functional component or stateful component etc

Comment: I can think of at least two things that are not components: hooks and React elements

Answer (score 2):

Components are independent and reusable code. They serve the same purpose as JavaScript functions, but work in isolation and returns HTML via a render function